# nested_set Gemfile syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gemfile

in my Gemfile

`gem 'nested_set', git: 'git://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set.git', tag: '~> 1.7.0' # September 11, 2013. To fix the error of wrong format of nested_st for 1.7.0`

but when I run rails s, I got this error.

`emfile:33: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'nested_set', git: 'git://github.com/skyeagle/ne...
                      ^`

how can I fix it? thanks!

Comment: Can you show the whole gemfile as-is?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using Ruby 1.9+.

The problem is that you're using the *JSON*-like notation which is not supported by ruby 1.8